# FBSDK Error Android React Native

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk

I am having problems running the `react-native run-android` command, and this only happens with `Android`, in iOS everything is working correctly (including login with Facebook).
The error that appears in the terminal.

> ```
> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> > 
> > * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> > > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
> >    > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fbsdk'.
> >       > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-fbsdk:_debugPublishCopy'.
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.53.0
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0 >
> > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.2/support-core-utils-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.2/support-core-utils-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.2/support-core-utils-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0 >
> > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0 >
> > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.31.0
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0 >
> > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.31.0
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0 >
> > com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.31.0
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.2/cardview-v7-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.2/cardview-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.2/cardview-v7-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0 >
> > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.31.0
> >          > Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2.
> >            Searched in the following locations:
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.2/customtabs-27.0.2.pom
> >                file:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.2/customtabs-27.0.2.jar
> >                file:/Users/rafaelaugusto/Documents/Aplicativos/ReactNative/Vesti/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.2/customtabs-27.0.2.jar
> >            Required by:
> >                Vesti:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0 >
> > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.31.0
> ```

I have tried some solutions that I found on the internet, and so far I have not been successful, through research in Google and here I managed to solve the error that happened in `iOS`, but I could not do the same with `Android`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the build.gradle

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
                }
            }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }

        }
    }
```